# Schengen tourist visa info

Tags: visas, schengen

If schengen visa get refused from Hungary embassy in India..
Is there any chance to get it if i apply from France embassy in kolkata (i saw its rejection rate is only 3%),after changing flight ticket.

Or shall i reapply from Hungary itself?

Comment: What reason was given for the refusal? If you don't fix that you're likely to get refused wherever you apply. Further, the French will know about a previous Schengen refusal, so they might suspect you of visa-shoppjng and refuse to look at your application at all.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You should not try to reapply from a different embassy. You will only be refused again. You should instead try to fix the problems with your original visa application.

Comment: Note that you're expected to apply to the country that is the main destination of your trip. If you're travelling mostly to Hungary, you need to apply to Hungary.

Answer (score 3):

Consider why **you** were refused the visa. There may be small differences in the acceptance rate, but that can change if some clerk gets reassigned to another desk. The rules are the same all across the Schengen area.

You wanted a tourist visa.

- Did the trip you were planning make sense for a tourist?
- Can you *reasonably* afford the trip from your regular income and expenses? If not, there has to be a very good explanation where the money comes from and why you spend it.
- Do you have a good reason to return to India?

Consider what your rejection said.